# Meaning of 事実としてそう、と言われたら納得せざるを得ない

Tags: grammar

> 「私は確かに相当な寒がりだけど、でもあの里が寒すぎてヤバい」
>
> 「だから超厚着するのがデフォで雪女は基本みんな体温が低い」
>
> 「でも寒いと体って発熱するんじゃなかったっけ？」
>
> 「さぁ。そんなこと言われても」
>
> 「……まぁそうだよな、ごめん」
>
> **事実としてそう**、と言われたら納得せざるを得ない。
>
> まぁ経緯はどうあれ優が寒がりなのは事実なわけだし。

My question is more about the **事実としてそう** at the start of the sentence and to what it is referring to. Based on the above conversation it seems that it's pointing to how he thinks that if your body is cold it generates heat, but she responds with そんなこと言われても which is sometimes said when むちゃくちゃなこと言われた. So, in this case is it like "Well, she's the one who is a 雪女 and if she's telling me that's not the case, then who am I to argue?".

edit: The thing is, if this was what it was referring to I would expect it to be そうではない etc. So anyone care to clarify what is being spoken about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, 事実としてそう、と言われたら納得せざるを得ない 'there is no way to argue the case when the fact has been told' is like a prelude to refer the following sentence. So, まぁ経緯はどうあれ優が寒がりなのは事実なわけだし 'it is true that 優 easily feels/gets cold no matter the background is', is indicating the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

It's equivalent to 「事実としてそうだ」と言われれば、納得せざるをえない. It means "If I'm told 'that is empirically the case', I have to accept that".